# How to switch to Login window using obj-c in Mac OS 10.6+

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, authentication, window

I have an app and I need to switch to Login window programmatically similar to this application:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lock-me-now/id464265594?mt=12

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to switch user:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -switchToUserID UserID
```

for UserID

```
id -u userName
```

For login Window

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I'm looking for. Sadly, it's not compatible with the new app sandboxing.

Answer (score 3):

You send an «aevtlogo» Apple Event to the `loginwindow` app. Look at the documentation for `NSAppleEvent<Foo>` classes.

Comment: It's a *LOT* easier to send Apple Events from Cocoa using Mike Ash's [AEVTBuilder](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?AEVTBuilder) class. Otherwise there's a fair amount of mucking about.